# Flutter app (dart) Enable orders only in specific area otherwise show message "not yet available to your area"

Tags: android, flutter, dart, geolocation

I need some help/advice/guidance. Actually if you could point me to the correct place.

I need the first app screen to load only if the user is within a specific area (for example a city, or country). i am developing the app with Flutter and dart.

The main.dart shows a loading indicator until the location is fetched (async).

What i would like to do is to be able to define the region this app works.

so if the current location is within the enabled region, the first screen will load. Elsewhere show a message that the app is not yet available in this region.

Any ideas?

Comment: try geo fencing, use it according to your need.

Comment: Define the region in what way? By zip code? Telephone area code? Distance from a Lat/Long coordinate?  There are a lot of ways to define a "geographic region", so your first step should be pinning down exactly what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geo-fencing can solve your problem.

1. send your location to the server-side.
2. evaluate if that location is within your service area.

Comment: Thank you to all. Geo-fencing is the answer